# Showing that $O(a)\times O(b)$ is maximal compact in $O(a,b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $O(a,b)=\{A\in Gl(n,\mathbb{C}) |\ A^TI_{a,b}A=I\}$ where $a+b=n$ and $I_{a,b}=\begin{bmatrix}I_a & 0 \\ 0 & -I_b \end{bmatrix}$. I want to determine the maximal compact subgroup of $O(a,b)$. I've found online that this is the group $O(a)\times O(b)=\{\begin{bmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}\ |\ A\in O(a),B\in O(b)\}$. I've managed to show that $O(a)\times O(b)$ it is a compact subgroup, however I'm having trouble with showing that it's maximal. Any hint is appriciated.

Comment: Hint : use the polar decomposition

Comment: So I guess we supose there exist maximal compact subgroup $M$ st. $O(a)\times O(b)< M<O(a,b)$, and use the polar decomposition on an element $m\in M$ st. $m=op$ where $o\in O(n)$ and $p$ is positive definite. Using compactness we may find a $K$ st. $K\geq ||x^n||$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So I'm guessing we somehow need to find a connection between $x$ and $p$, so way may conclude $p=I$, meaning $M=O(a,b)$, right? However I'm having trouble with doing (if it's even the right strategy).

Comment: Yes that's the idea. You can try to prove that $o\in O(a,b)$ and that $O(a,b)\cap O(n) = O(a)\times O(b)$

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes sense! Why does $o\in O(a,b)$, because that would mean $o^TI_{a,b}o=(mp^{-1})^TI_{a,b}mp^{-1}=p^{-1}m^TI_{a,b}mp^{-1}=p^{-1}Ip^{-1}=p^{-2}$ which should equal $I$, which seems a little odd to me?

Comment: Use the fact that $m\in O(a,b)$ to find a second polar decomposition of $m$, then use the uniqueness (note that you made a mistake : $m^TI_{a,b}m = I_{a,b}$, not $I$ !)

Comment: How do one use the uniqueness? (sorry for asking so much)

Comment: $m = I_{a,b}(m^T)^{-1}I_{a,b}$ and $m= op$ (to substitue on the RHS) will give you another polar decomposition if you stare at it long enough

Comment: So I guess we get $op=m=I_{a,b}(o^T)^{-1}p^{-1}I_{p,q}$, however I don't see why $p^{-1}I_{p,q}$ is necessarily positive definite, so use uniqueness and concluding $o=I_{a,b}(o^T)^{-1}$?

Comment: You actually have to add some $I_{a,b}$'s here and there in your formula. Remember that $I_{a,b}^2 = I_n$